# Solving a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with solving this differential equation.
$$\frac{k\ell+y}{\ell\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}}=c$$

$$y'(x) = \pm\left(\left(\frac{k\ell+y(x)}{c\ell}\right)^2-1\right)^{1/2}$$
What should I do after I've expressed $y′$ as a function of $y$?
How should I integrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: solve for $y'(x)$ 
$$\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{kl+y}{cl}\right)^2-1}=y'$$
and then integrate
$$\int dx=\pm\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{kl+y}{cl}\right)^2-1}}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: first express $y'$ as a function of $y$.  The result should be a separable differential equation.